# Is there a site that generates all possible ways of displaying a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++

I need to generate all likely possible ways of writing a word (for a banned words list).

Basically if someone says something like dicora(just for example)...
Some possible ways of writing this word to avoid the banned words list filter would be as d1cora, dic0ra, dicor@, d1cOra, etc....

I know I can probably just write a program that writes all possible versions of word by replacing each individual letter at a time with it's matched counterpart in C++ or Java, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here if I don't have to.

I'm wondering if there is a tool out there that will generate the different versions of a word for me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This will not work. You will either ban way too much (the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)) or way too little. Even if you could distinguish these words perfectly, you'd still have problems with all the words that are okay in one context and not in another. Someone deliberately trying to get through your filter will just use those. And if you're just trying to catch people doing things by accident, you don't need all these variations.

The Royal Society for the Protection of Birds famously upgraded their forum software to find that the words "booby" and "shag" were now banned. Both of these are names for types of birds.

Many well-financed, highly motivated groups have tried to do this, and they've all produced very poor results. Instead, just list the words the way they'd normally be written to make sure everyone knows the rules and have humans enforce the rules. This is the kind of decision computers are not yet good at making.